# typescript can't find module less

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, webpack, single-page-application

[image]

I use react and webpack to build web SPA but, typescript can't find resolve the less file

[image]

work file like this ⬆️

Comment: Please share some of your code so we can help.

Comment: Please show more context (directory structure with file names, etc).

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Comment: you can refer this as well [How to import a scss file into a typescript file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60029264/2443988)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Just create a new declaration file (`externals.d.ts`) with `declare module '*.less'`.

**Edit**
If you are using [css-modules](https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules), you can define these types to match the return value:

```
declare module '*.less' {
  const resource: {[key: string]: string};
  export = resource;
}
```

Add that file to the `includes` array of your `tsconfig.json` file.

```
// tsconfig.json
{
   compilerOptions: {...}
   includes: [
      './path/to/the/new/file/externals.d.ts'
   ]
}
```

Comment: Killed couple of _hours_, trying to solve this %) Thank you for help!

Answer (score 14):

Add to `src/react-app-env.d.ts` or `declaration.d.ts`

```js
declare module '*.less';
```

or if you use `css-modules`

```js
declare module '*.module.less' {
  const classes: { [className: string]: string };
  export default classes;
}
```