# How to import a scss file into a typescript file

Tags: reactjs, typescript, sass

I am trying to import a .scss file into a .tsx typescript file.

However i get the following error. When i run `npm run tsc`

> src/public/app1/index.tsx:5:20 - error TS2307: Cannot find module
>   './index.scss'.
>
> 5 import styles from "./index.scss";
>                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>
> Found 1 error.

**index.tsx**

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";
import styles from "./index.scss";

render(
    <App/>,
    document.getElementById("root"),
);
```

**index.scss**

```
body {
    background:red;
    color: #005CC5;
    text-align: center;
}
```

I saw one solution was to create a decleration.d.ts file in the root of my project. But this has not worked for me. [Can't import CSS/SCSS modules. TypeScript says "Cannot Find Module"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40382842/cant-import-css-scss-modules-typescript-says-cannot-find-module)

**decleration.d.ts**

```
declare module '*.scss';
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    /* Basic Options */
    // "incremental": true,                   /* Enable incremental compilation */
    "target": "es6",                          /* Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), 'ES5', 'ES2015', 'ES2016', 'ES2017', 'ES2018', 'ES2019' or 'ESNEXT'. */
    "module": "commonjs",                     /* Specify module code generation: 'none', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es2015', or 'ESNext'. */
    // "lib": [],                             /* Specify library files to be included in the compilation. */
    // "allowJs": true,                       /* Allow javascript files to be compiled. */
    // "checkJs": true,                       /* Report errors in .js files. */
    "jsx": "react",                     /* Specify JSX code generation: 'preserve', 'react-native', or 'react'. */
    // "declaration": true,                   /* Generates corresponding '.d.ts' file. */
    // "declarationMap": true,                /* Generates a sourcemap for each corresponding '.d.ts' file. */
    // "sourceMap": true,                     /* Generates corresponding '.map' file. */
    // "outFile": "./",                       /* Concatenate and emit output to single file. */
    "outDir": "./build",                        /* Redirect output structure to the directory. */
    "rootDir": "./src",                       /* Specify the root directory of input files. Use to control the output directory structure with --outDir. */
    // "composite": true,                     /* Enable project compilation */
    // "tsBuildInfoFile": "./",               /* Specify file to store incremental compilation information */
    // "removeComments": true,                /* Do not emit comments to output. */
    // "noEmit": true,                        /* Do not emit outputs. */
    // "importHelpers": true,                 /* Import emit helpers from 'tslib'. */
    // "downlevelIteration": true,            /* Provide full support for iterables in 'for-of', spread, and destructuring when targeting 'ES5' or 'ES3'. */
    // "isolatedModules": true,               /* Transpile each file as a separate module (similar to 'ts.transpileModule'). */

    /* Strict Type-Checking Options */
    "strict": true,                           /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */
    // "noImplicitAny": true,                 /* Raise error on expressions and declarations with an implied 'any' type. */
    // "strictNullChecks": true,              /* Enable strict null checks. */
    // "strictFunctionTypes": true,           /* Enable strict checking of function types. */
    // "strictBindCallApply": true,           /* Enable strict 'bind', 'call', and 'apply' methods on functions. */
    // "strictPropertyInitialization": true,  /* Enable strict checking of property initialization in classes. */
    // "noImplicitThis": true,                /* Raise error on 'this' expressions with an implied 'any' type. */
    // "alwaysStrict": true,                  /* Parse in strict mode and emit "use strict" for each source file. */

    /* Additional Checks */
    // "noUnusedLocals": true,                /* Report errors on unused locals. */
    // "noUnusedParameters": true,            /* Report errors on unused parameters. */
    // "noImplicitReturns": true,             /* Report error when not all code paths in function return a value. */
    // "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,    /* Report errors for fallthrough cases in switch statement. */

    /* Module Resolution Options */
    "moduleResolution": "node",            /* Specify module resolution strategy: 'node' (Node.js) or 'classic' (TypeScript pre-1.6). */
    "baseUrl": "./src",                       /* Base directory to resolve non-absolute module names. */
    // "paths": {},                           /* A series of entries which re-map imports to lookup locations relative to the 'baseUrl'. */
    // "rootDirs": [],                        /* List of root folders whose combined content represents the structure of the project at runtime. */
    // "typeRoots": [],                       /* List of folders to include type definitions from. */
    // "types": [],                           /* Type declaration files to be included in compilation. */
    // "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,  /* Allow default imports from modules with no default export. This does not affect code emit, just typechecking. */
    "esModuleInterop": true                   /* Enables emit interoperability between CommonJS and ES Modules via creation of namespace objects for all imports. Implies 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports'. */
    // "preserveSymlinks": true,              /* Do not resolve the real path of symlinks. */
    // "allowUmdGlobalAccess": true,          /* Allow accessing UMD globals from modules. */

    /* Source Map Options */
    // "sourceRoot": "",                      /* Specify the location where debugger should locate TypeScript files instead of source locations. */
    // "mapRoot": "",                         /* Specify the location where debugger should locate map files instead of generated locations. */
    // "inlineSourceMap": true,               /* Emit a single file with source maps instead of having a separate file. */
    // "inlineSources": true,                 /* Emit the source alongside the sourcemaps within a single file; requires '--inlineSourceMap' or '--sourceMap' to be set. */

    /* Experimental Options */
    // "experimentalDecorators": true,        /* Enables experimental support for ES7 decorators. */
    // "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,         /* Enables experimental support for emitting type metadata for decorators. */
  },
  "include": [
    "src",
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Generally the framework finds the SCSS file that matches the name of your TS file found in the same folder. You don't need to import this yourself.

Comment: What framework?

Comment: If i have many .scss files i need to import them into react to use them. Sorry im misunderstanding your point?

Comment: You had "reactjs" as one of your tags. That would be your framework, React.

Comment: Yep, but im not using create-react-app.

Comment: Are you saying i don't need to import any scss files into my tsx files? What if the scss file is located in a sub directory and i wanted to use it in a tsx file located in another directory... or they were named differently?

Comment: and just fyi, i removed the import statement so it built but the styles were not applied. So it doesen't look like its finding the scss file that matches the name o the ts file.

Comment: I'm also having this issue Kay. Make any progress?  And @Diodeus, it is fairly common practice to import SCSS files directly into the TS.

Comment: ye i did in the src of your react app add a `global.d.ts` file inside add `declare module "*.scss";`

Comment: then your webpack should have something like this https://pastebin.com/QWQgMCVh

Answer (score 31):

As [OP mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56563243/how-to-import-a-scss-file-into-a-typescript-file#comment100908682_56563243), the current solution is to add a file called `global.d.ts` to your `src` dir with the following contents

```
declare module '*.scss';
```

In my case, I'm using `rollup-plugin-lit-css` to import CSS as js objects. I had to create a `/typings/declarations.d.ts` file,

```
declare module '*.css' {
  import { CSSResult } from 'lit-element';
  const css: CSSResult;
  export default css;
}
```

and reference it in tsconfig like so:

```
{
  "include": [ "typings", "src" ],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNext",
    "module": "CommonJS",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "checkJs": true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had this same issue and created a declarations file in the root directory. I then included it in the tsconfig.json.

**declarations.d.ts**

```
declare module "*.scss" {
    const content: {[className: string]: string};
    export = content;
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
"include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "declarations.d.ts"
]
```

Answer (score -3):

Have you just tried `import "./index.scss";` ?